# как соединить три таблицы в одну

Tags: sql, teradata

есть 3 таблицы, нужно из этих 3-х сделать одну, чтобы получить все возможные варианты соединений. пример:

```
таблица 1
Carrier
GTK
BEE

таблица 2
Operator
ООО "Инком"
ООО "РТС Телеком"

таблица 3
Region
р-н Шацкий|Рязанская обл.
р-н Северский|Краснодарский край
```

т.е. в итоге я хочу получить все варианты соединения

```
таблица 4
GTK ООО "Инком" р-н Шацкий|Рязанская обл.
GTK ООО "Инком" р-н Северский|Краснодарский край
GTK ООО "РТС Телеком" р-н Шацкий|Рязанская обл.
GTK ООО "РТС Телеком" р-н Северский|Краснодарский край
BEE ООО "Инком" р-н Шацкий|Рязанская обл.
BEE ООО "Инком" р-н Северский|Краснодарский край
BEE ООО "РТС Телеком" р-н Шацкий|Рязанская обл.
BEE ООО "РТС Телеком" р-н Северский|Краснодарский край
```

реально ли это вообще сделать в teradata? (больше инструментов нет, к сожалению)

Comment: Вообще в `SQL` это называется `CROSS JOIN` если не путаю, но вот конкретно в `teradata` - не знаю как.

Comment: насколько я понимаю, cross join по идее подходит, но он делает соединение на основе общих столбцов / значений из этих таблиц, а у меня этих общих значений нет. нужен либо какой-то другой вариант, либо как-то добавить это общее значение

Comment: *но он делает соединение на основе общих столбцов / значений из этих таблиц* Нет. Как раз CROSS JOIN производит генерацию всех сочетаний вне зависимости от чего-либо.

Comment: да, точно, все получилось, спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Для того, чтобы получить все возможные сочетания, в `SQL` используется `CROSS JOIN`. Судя по [документации](https://docs.teradata.com/r/2_MC9vCtAJRlKle2Rpb0mA/37spXHml4asJ9XP0SsnwXQ), в `teradata` его можно использовать как в явном виде:

```sql
SELECT ...
FROM table_a 
CROSS JOIN table_b;
```

Так и в неявном, просто сделав `SELECT` из нескольких таблиц без условия:

```sql
SELECT ...
FROM table_a,table_b;
```